# RewriteRule to remove version number

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have implemented a cache busting solution on a site where a version number is added to the end of the file name, before the file extension. However I am having an issue with one of the rules not working.

Typical requests:

```
/static/deploy/styles/site_78_direct.min.0.css
/static/deploy/styles/ie/site_78_direct.0.css
```

I need the above to be redirected to the following:

```
/static/deploy/styles/site_78_direct.min.css
/static/deploy/styles/ie/site_78_direct.css
```

I came up with the following which half works:

```
RewriteRule ^/static/deploy/styles/ie/(.*).([0-9]+).css$ /static/deploy/styles/ie/$1.css [L]
RewriteRule ^/static/deploy/(scripts|styles)/(.*).min.([0-9]+).(js|css)$ /static/deploy/$1/$2.min.$4 [L]
```

The above redirects properly but I want it to ignore the following:

```
/static/deploy/styles/ie/site_78_direct-blessed1.css
```

I basically only want to redirect if there is a number between fullstops, i.e. .0.css

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to escape the dot otherwise it will match any character.

Besides just this single rule should work for both cases:

```
RewriteRule ^(/?static/deploy/.+?)\.\d+\.(js|css)$ $1.$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Works as expected, thank you. Just need to remove the final closing bracket. Thank you!

Comment: How can this be done using a file name like `mycss.1.0.0.css`? I've tried `RewriteRule ^(/?static/deploy/.+?)\.\d+\.(js|css)$ $1.$2.$3.$4 [L,NC]` but no luck :(

Comment: @newplayer65 Try `RewriteRule ^(/?static/deploy/.*?)(?:.\d+)+\.(js|css)$ $1.$2 [L,NC]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @anubhava ! I'm gonna try that out later. I was looking around for some good tutorials on making rewrite rules, but they all confuse me. Do you know of any good tutorials for anybody who hasn't written a regex before?

Comment: You can check regular-expressions. Info website